# Error with Akka

Tags: compiler-errors, akka

I am using akka and it is giving me an error whenever I use ActorSystem.

The error is:

> Bad symbolic reference. A signature in ActorSystem.class refers to term config in value com.typesafe which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling ActorSystem.class.

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) from your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Update scala dependencies in build-path (Project -> Build path -> Configure Build path) ,  to point to libraries from your scala-home. ( **including typsafe-config.jar**)

[image]